# TemplateURL in Bower Component [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

I have created a custom bower component which consists of several directives.

Each of these directives have a templateUrl associated with them e.g.:

```
templateUrl: 'bower_components/my.component/component.html'
```

When I test my directive locally, the above resource works properly, but when I am testing on my QA server, this resource is undefined and the directive fails.

Each of these html templates are in the same directory as the directive file. How can I access these templates when I install my component in other applications?

Edit:
Basic Application hierarchy:

```
app -> scripts, styles, etc
bower_components -> All of my required components for my application
bower.json -> Included my bower dependency
```

Then my bower component structure is as such:

```
my.component -> component.html, component2.html, component.js (where my directives are), component.css
```

etc.

The templates from my new component inside of bower_components need to be used by the directives inside of my new component inside of bower_components

Comment: Have you tried to open this file from browser? Have you sure this file is available on browser?

Comment: Are you using  tools like grunt or gulp to compile scripts?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using grunt in my applications

Comment: So does that compile all the scripts needed from bower_components into different directory and insert from there into page....thereby meaning you don't need to upload bower_comonents to QA server?

Comment: One suggestion is have grunt inject html into your directive module `dist` version as `$templateCache('my.component/component.html', html_string)` and use that as `templateUrl`.

Comment: @charlietfl I updated my question with my application hierarchy, but let me give that a shot and see if I can get it working

Comment: Example would be how angular-ui-bootstrap does same thing in their module version that includes templates. Then you only need one js file for whole directive/module